# Error: 'Property context does not exist on type jQuery'

Tags: jquery

I am trying to upgrade jQuery but there's one error I am not able to fix. jQuery is only used in a limited part of the code, and it can't be removed at this point, but it needs upgrading from 2.x to latest.

Currently I have this:

```
constructor(..., $element: JQuery) {
  super($element.find(".modal"));
  this.domElement = $($element.context.firstElementChild);
  this.domElement.on("show.bs.modal", () => this.onShow());

  // ...
```

I get this error:

> Property 'context' does not exist on type 'JQuery'

What has it been replaced with? All I found was information that it has been deprecated in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/context/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`context` hasn't been replaced. However you can get to the Element object within a jQuery object using bracket notation, `$element[0]`, or `get()`, `$element.get(0)`. From there you would use `firstElementChild()` as normal.

```
this.domElement = $($element[0].firstElementChild);
```

That being said, that line of code is getting a Element object from a jQuery object only to turn it back in to a jQuery object again - which is not ideal.

A better approach would be to just select the first child from `$element` using jQuery, like this:

```
this.domElement = $element.children().first();
```